# CakePHP correct syntax to print out variable

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a beginners question about CakePHP. I'm trying to print out data I got from database to view but I cannot figure out correct syntax how to do it.
I have variable $title in the view.ctp in which there are data I need to print out. I used debug on the $title variable and I got this print out:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'posts' => array(
            'title' => 'The title'
        )
    )
)
```

But when I try to print out just the title ('The title'), it gives me an error:

> Notice (8): Undefined index: posts [APP/View/Posts/view.ctp, line 3]

To print out the title I'm using:

```
echo h($title['posts']['title']);
```

What's the correct way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: should be `$title[0]['posts']['title']`

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: Could you show your query? You shouldn't have model with `-s` on end(`posts`).

Comment: It's working now. Thanks for help. I just had to add [0] as Nunser said.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
echo h($title[0]['posts']['title']);
```

Comment: Lose the H before echo ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

if(isset($title)){
    echo ($title[0]['posts']['title']);
} 

?>
```